# Does Kurento support the function to send RTCP FIR packets when a key frame is needed?

Tags: kurento, rtcp

I'm using Kurento 6.0 and 7.0. 
Based on my test results, it appears that Kurento doesn't send RTCP FIR packets even when it doesn't decode incoming VP8 packets due to a missing key frame. 
In a real video call environment, key frames can occasionally be dropped. 
Does Kurento support the function to send RTCP FIR packets when a key frame is needed?